# How can I get photos in iPhone by wire?

Tags: iphone, photos, file-transfer

I need to get photos from my Mac to my iPhone, but best way I found was by AirDrop, but it is too slow (I need to transfer lot of photos).
I would think that it would be faster by wire, but I didn't find any way...

Answer (score 1):

Let iTunes do that for you, check how to do it here in the [apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201313)

Here's what the overall steps are as described in the link in case it dies:

1. Make sure that you have the latest version of iTunes.
2. Open iTunes on your computer.
3. Use the included USB cable to connect your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch to your computer.
4. Click on the device icon in iTunes.
5. Click Photos in the sidebar.
6. Click the box next to "Sync Photos." If instead you see "iCloud Photos is On," all your photos and videos are already on all of your devices that use iCloud Photo Library. You don't need to sync them through iTunes.
7. In the drop-down menu, choose the app or folder that you want to sync from.
8. Choose to sync all photos or selected albums. 
   Select "Include videos" to sync the videos from your app or folder too.
   Click Apply.

There are also 3rd party apps like [RollIt](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rollit-photo-transfer-app/id741790426?l=fr&ls=1&mt=8) that does that job too without iTunes, however it's paid